# How to upload shapefile and merge with CSV in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, geospatial

I'm trying r shiny about spatial analysis with my r code:

```
parks = read_sf("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/Jawa barat")
dbd_sementara=read.table(file.choose(),header = T, sep = ";")
head(dbd_sementara)
newdata = merge(parks, dbd_sementara, by = "Kabupaten_")
pl <- st_cast(newdata$geometry[[4]], "POLYGON")
spd <- sf::as_Spatial(st_geometry(pl))
class(spd)
df <- pl
df$geometry <- NULL
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
temp<-poly2nb(newdata)
W<-nb2mat(temp, style = "B", zero.policy = TRUE)
W.list <- nb2listw(temp, style="B")
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, ca. Please help solve the issue by trimming your code down to a minimal reproducible example. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example